# Does s3.get_object() download a file when I try to read it?

Tags: python, boto3

Does s3.get_object() download a file when you use read(), I mean does it create a temporary file in disk? or does it read it in memory?

Answer (score 0):

The [response](https://botocore.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/response.html) contains a StreamingBody which is a boto3 wrapper for a [stream](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html).

If you invoke [read](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#readablereadsize) on the stream then you get a buffer. Alternatively, you can stream the data to a file or other destination.